# What does "full array operation" mean for EEPROM?

Tags: eeprom

What is full array operation as shown in [data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc5226.pdf) of AT24C08B: Two-wire Serial EEPROM (page3)? What is application of that full array operation? Please help to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Write protection* pin prevents the memory from being written on. In page 3 the datasheet explains that asserting (pulling high) that pin makes the whole memory array to be protected from *write* operations.